# a href inside div opening a new page/tab

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div and I have a link inside this div.  I want the user to be able to click anywhere in the div and they go to the page that's in the link.  The link can be changed to a `<span>/<p>`, that's not important.  There are the following conditions, however:

1. I cannot use css to make the `<a>` tags into `display: block;`
2. If I use onClick I want the user to be able to use the middle-mouse button (or right click, new tab) to open the page in a new tab if they so desire.  I currently do not have this functionality if I use onClick and javascript.
3. I want it to be valid CSS i.e. I don't want to have `<a><div> .... </div></a>`

That pretty much sums up the problem I have.  I've tried reading around but most people seem to solve the problem with either onclick, display: block or putting images, or forcing the user to open the page in a new window.  I do not want any of these solutions, I just want a div to work as a normal link (if possible).

Many thanks

Comment: You've thrown a bunch of requirements at us and excluded many of the popular workarounds, but you have not explained why you want it like this or what your end goal is supposed to be.  If I already have jQuery loaded, I'd just bind `click` to the `div`.  Since you don't mention jQuery, using an image inside `<a></a>` in place of the `div` seems like the most logical and semantically correct solution.

Comment: That's because I know all of the workarounds and I want to know if there is a "proper" way to do it.  I will look into the jquery click as I use jquery a lot on my website already.  I did mention that I don't want to use images in the second paragraph.

Comment: I know you already said you don't want to use images. That's why I posted it as a comment and not an answer.  In other words, I'm telling you that it's actually one good way of doing it despite your unknown reasons for excluding it.  Again, you never stated _"why"_ you have to do this, so your answers are going to be more limited.

Comment: And what's your current mark-up, and what have you tried to do already? What went wrong?

Comment: Another technique could be to, on page load, take the `A` tag out of the `div` tag and wrap it around the `div`. It's only "invalid" on page parse, after that they're just DOM elements.

Comment: @Sparky672 I am asking why just because I want to find out if there is a "proper" method of doing it instead of annoying work-arounds.  If I can do something properly, it's better to ask and find out what that is.

Comment: @DavidThomas I have used various methods in the past.  I just wanted to know if there was an easy and proper way to do it without having to do workarounds.

Comment: The easiest, most proper way (until HTML5) is to use `display: block` on the `a`.

Comment: @JaredFarrish see point 1 I made in the original question.

Comment: What kind of question asks _"what's the proper way?"_ while excluding all the proper ways?  Those kinds of questions have no good answers.

Comment: @Sparky672 There's a very big difference between using valid markup which is considered correct as opposed to a piece of code that happens to work in all browsers but is messy and isn't considered correct.  I am here to learn from others and find out if there is a better way than I currently know.

Comment: @James, you've also excluded "proper & valid markup" though.  (See last comment by Jared Farrish.)  And I certainly have not once suggested using any solution containing invalid markup.

Comment: @Sparky672 that assumes that I am calling the html 5 doctype..

Comment: That is **NOT** what he said.  He said _"**UNTIL** HTML5"_ use  "`display: block` on the `a`".

Comment: @Sparky672 Please refer to point number 1 in the original question.

Comment: We are going in circles...  point 1 in your original question is excluding "proper" and "valid" markup, hence my comment that you have excluded any possible "valid & proper" solution.

Comment: @Sparky672 - Calm down, there isn't any use in getting angry. James, if you could provide the markup and/or a http://jsfiddle.com/ demo, that would help greatly. It's really difficult to understand your problem enough to suggest solutions.

Comment: @Sparky672 It appears we are going around in circles.  If you read my comments to the other answers, you'll see that I am restricted by factors that are out of my control.  Using display: block; does not work with the current markup.  I didn't create it, it's old and I have no time to re-write the entire page layout again.  That is the reason I have to remove this solution.

Comment: I know James & Jared, I'm not angry at all... but you seem to have excluded all the proper ways to do this, leaving you with no solution that can meet your requirements.  Like Jared suggested, add a jsFiddle and more information to your OP about why you are restricted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try wrapping the A tag with your DIV instead of vice-versa.

Instead of:

```
<div><a>link</a></div>
```

Try:

```
<a><div>link</div></a>
```

So, maybe it's not valid mark up (before HTML5) but the fact that it is now acceptable by HTML5 standards seems like hindsight that this is at least a *good* way to accomplish what you need.

Comment: That wouldn't be considered valid CSS though, even though it may work.

Comment: In HTML 5, you can actually do this and it's still valid. And it's not that it's "valid CSS", it's "valid markup".

Comment: @James Valid CSS? I think you mean HTML. Alternatively just using an A tag with display:block and width/height may do the trick.

Comment: my mistake, i am rather distracted at the moment with stuff so I wrote something that made no sense.  Either way, I am sure there must be a method that doesn't seem so messy.  Having inline tags surrounding block tags just doesn't do it for me, even though it may work, it's very messy..

Comment: @James I do it all the time (inline tags around block level) and the browsers don't complain.  Anyway, what is to stop you from just using an A tag with display: block?

Comment: @Matt - That's invalid markup (until HTML 5) to have an inline wrapping a block.

Comment: @Matt As I commented on another answer a moment ago, I cannot use display block as it clashes with some other content on the page.  I have a old and complex layout which I am attempting to add to, this is why I am very restricted in my choices.

Comment: @James Even if you only used classes on the A tags that you _want_ to have display:block?  I'm just curious how it would clash with the other content on the page if you only set specific A tags to be block level elements thereby replacing your need for block level DIVs.

Comment: @Matt If I understood that problem I wouldn't be here asking for alterntive methods :) If I add "display: block;" to that specific <a> tag inside my div, other elements on the DOM stop working.  I don't fully understand why, but I didn't build it and it's old, so I want to find alternative methods.  So far, your method of adding <a> tags around the <div> tags is working, even though it's causing me irritation just looking at it lol :)

Comment: It used to bother me too but I got over it :) Now the only thing that bothers me is unclosed BR tags.

Comment: @Matt haha, maybe I'll just use it and never open the script again :)

Answer (score 1):

The middle-mouse/right click functions are part of how the browser interacts with an anchor, not part of your code. There's nothing you can do in code to make it work different. If changing the anchor to take up the whole space (act like a DIV) isn't possible, I don't see how you're going to do this in exactly the same way.

You could approximate it by detecting which mouse button is pressed with `event.which` and doing different things based on which mouse button is clicked.  It won't be the browser interface that the user is interacting with and some of the options may not be possible, but you could make it close.

```
$('#myDiv').mousedown( function(e) {
    var href = $(this).find('a:first').attr('href');
    if (e.which == 1) {
        window.parent.location = href;
    }
    else if (e.which == 2) {
        window.open(href);
    }
    else {
        ...popup a menu with the various options...
    }
});

// prevent all clicks on the actual anchor from bubbling to the DIV handler
$('#myDiv a').click(function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One way that I have approached this in the past is to wrap the div inside of the  tag.

So, try something like this

```
<a href="someplace"><div style="min-width: 20px; min-height: 20px;">test</div></a>
```

Comment: That wouldn't be considered valid CSS though, even though it may work.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can make `<a>`tags into `display: block;` but be careful you need to add `height: inherit;` if you don't want to set a fixed height

**Update:**
onclick event can't handle right click and middle click but onmousedown can!
Example:

```
$("a").mousedown(function(e){
    switch(e.which)
    {
        case 1: //left click
            $(this).attr("target", "_self"); //this tab
        break;
        case 2: case 3: // right and middle click
            $(this).attr("target", "_blank"); //new tab
            e.preventDefault();
        break;
    }
});
```

Comment: The question states "*I cannot use css to make the `<a>` tags into `display: block`*". I don't know why the OP can't, but that's what it says.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I am modifying an extremely complex existing page layout.  This is the main reason I am extremely restricted.

Comment: @James - Is it a selector problem, ie, you don't feel you could adequately target the `a` elements without affecting other elements?

Comment: @JaredFarrish no it's not a selector problem.  it's just that display: block; is conflicting with the existing layout (even when I tried height: inherit) so this method does not work.  I tried this before coming here, that's why I am asking the question :)